# Error while insert into FirebirdDB

Tags: php, objective-c, firebird

at first: sry for my bad english and i'm new at program PHP.

I'm trying to insert some Values from IOS to my Firebird DB over an PHP script.

But the script shows ibase-error:
"Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 182 ) "

my PHP-code:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'postValues'){ 
$host = xxx;
$username = xxx;
$password = xxx;
$conn = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password) or 
die ("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");

$Benutzer_Nachricht = $_POST['NACHRICHT'];
$Benutzer_Nummer = $_POST['USER'];
$datum = date("d.m.Y H:i");
$Benutzer_AN = $_POST['AN'];
$Benutzer_BETREFF = $_POST['BETREFF'];
$Benutzer_KOM = $_POST['KOMMISSIONSNR'];
$Benutzer_AUFTRAG = $_POST['AUFTRAG'];

$Nachrichten_Status = 1;

$query = ("INSERT INTO TNACHRICHTEN( BETREFF, VON, AN, NACHRICHT, DATUM, STATUS, KOMMISSIONSNR, AUFTRAG) values($Benutzer_BETREFF,$Benutzer_Nummer,$Benutzer_AN,$Benutzer_Nachricht,'$datum','$Nachrichten_Status', $Benutzer_KOM, $Benutzer_Auftrag)");

$result=ibase_query($conn,$query);
if (!$result) {
echo json_encode(ibase_errmsg());
}
else
{
echo json_encode("NO Error. Can't insert the record with the query: $query!");
}
}
```

The values are given correctly to PHP.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please include the actual value of `$query`. You are using variable expansion in a string, this most likely causes the statement to be invalid (a syntax error) because you aren't quoting all values. It is also a very good way to get SQL injection. You should really use a proper parametrized SQL query.

Comment: Debug the query in IDE like IBExpert or at least Round Robin first,  then put it to the program code when it is made final

Comment: Use parameters in queries to keep your code safe from errors and crackers.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: i've testet for a while in IBExpert, now the code is working.
Unfortunately my app given an wrong String, but now everything works.
 Thank You!

Comment: Great! Yet i still suggest you using parameters instead of variable inlining. PHP does not have great record of safety, so please do more advanced techniques, separating queries from data (and providing for queries *preparing* when it suits)